# How to pass LinkedService parameter value to all dataset in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

I have created a parameter in the linked service of the oracle database connection and would like to get the value of the parameter to all datasets, I have created datasets for each table and would like to get oracleSchemeName parameter from the Linked service, In my scenario schema name will change based on environments, SO I passed schema name as parameter but when I'm trying to read the value of linked service, I am getting error table or view doesn't exist.

Can someone please guide me on how to provide expression here? {@linkedService().oracleSchemaName} --Not working.

Below is the screenshot of dataset

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`{@linkedService().SchemaName}` is invalid as schema name is not part of the linked service connection string. You can parameterize the properties which are part of the linked service [connection string properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#linked-service-properties).

**Example:**

[image]

If you want to pass the schema/table name dynamically, you can create a pipeline level parameter and pass the values in run time.

Steps to pass the table schema value dynamically at runtime:

1. Create a parameter at database level (SchemaName) and do not pass any value to it currently.

[image]

2. Edit the table and pass dataset parameter in add dynamic content.

[image]

3. Create a parameter at pipeline level and add the parameter dynamically in sink properties and do not pass any value to the parameter currently.

[image]

4. While running the pipeline, it will ask to pass value to the pipeline parameter, then pass the value and run the pipeline.

[image]

Reference: [Parameterize linked services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services)